# Passing a programmatically generated value from a listitem to a jquery function

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a datatable-generated list with a certain set of attributes. I'd like to pass a certain attribute to a jquery function, which will then add the attribute to POST and then redirect the user to another page. I'm not sure if this is the best approach, but I'm having trouble pulling it off.

Right now I'm just trying to test how to actually pass the value to the jquery function. Here is the codebehind that generates the list items:

```
protected void BuildReportList(DataTable dt)
{
  string groupHeader = "";
  foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
  {                
    ListItem myItem = new ListItem();
    myItem.Text = row["prg_menu"].ToString();
    myItem.Attributes.Add("title", row["prg_description"].ToString());
    myItem.Attributes.Add("onClick", "test();");
    myItem.Attributes.Add("value", row["prg_path"].ToString().Trim());
    reportsList.Items.Add(myItem);
  }
}
```

Here is the jquery function, which right now I'm just trying to pop an alert with the passed value:

```
function test() {
  alert(($this).attr("value"));
}
```

Any advice on what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
myItem.Attributes.Add("onClick", "test(this);");
```

And:

```
function test(item) {
  alert($(item).val());
}
```

There are more options to check element' value:

```
$(item).attr("value");
```

or without jQuery wrapping:

```
item.value;
```

Comment: That's actually tripping the alert now, which the previous did not, but it simply pops up "1" every time.

Comment: @Ben "1" is item's value , exactly what you need (*I'm just trying to pop an alert with the passed value*)

Comment: Sorry, I meant the value added as an attribute--row["prg_path"].ToString().Trim() in the code above.

For example, here's one of the list elements in the resulting html from the code above: <li title="SHOWS GROSS PROFIT AND COMMISSION BY MONTH FOR THE CURRENT  YEAR OR PRIOR YEAR COMPARED WITH GOAL." onClick="test(this);" value="gross profit report">GROSS PROFIT REPORT</li> The alert should throw "gross profit report" for this element.

Comment: So you want get the title or item's text? Try `alert($(item).html());`

Comment: That fetches the text variable, not the value attribute. This worked, though:

        function test(item) {
            alert($(item).attr("value"));
        }

Thanks!

Comment: @Ben  glad it helped! strange , `$(item).val()` and `$(item).attr("value")` must be actually the same...

Comment: They seem like they would be, but they're not. The first gives an alert of "1" when used, the second gives "gross profit report."

Comment: If you can edit your answer to what worked, I'll mark it as correct, thanks. :)

Comment: @Ben , ok , check it now ;)